# Textbox using textmode password not showing text asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, text, textbox, passwordbox

I have a few buttons on a web form, and when the user clicks them they will update the the textbox. This worked till I added the textmode = password. Now the textbox doesn't show the text anymore. I debugged the app, and the text property is getting the value, but once again it is not showing.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 protected void btn_punch_7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        const string string_punch_Number_7 = "7";
        var text = txt_punch.Text;
        text += string_punch_Number_7;

        txt_punch.Text = text;


    }

    protected void btn_punch_8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string string_punch_Number_8 = "8";
        var text = txt_punch.Text;
        text += string_punch_Number_8;

        txt_punch.Text = text;

    }
```

I have also tired this:

```
public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string string_punch;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View1);

        txt_punch.Width = 300;
        txt_punch.Height = 50;
        txt_punch.MaxLength = 4;
        txt_punch.Attributes.Add("OnChange", string_punch);

    }

    protected void btn_punch_7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        const string string_punch_Number_7 = "7";
        string_punch = txt_punch.Text;
        string_punch += string_punch_Number_7;

        txt_punch.Text = string_punch;


    }

    protected void btn_punch_8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string string_punch_Number_8 = "8";
        string_punch = txt_punch.Text;
        string_punch += string_punch_Number_8;

        txt_punch.Text = string_punch;

    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't force the text to be visible on a password field. If you force the text, then anybody can get the password by looking at the html for your site.

Comment: @bastos.sergio How big a problem is that? The HTML will not be stored anywhere. Unless the person typing the password will save the page to disk just before submitting.

Comment: It doesn't need to be stored... Try this, right click anywhere on a site and choose the option "view source code".  That's all you need to view the html...

Comment: sure, but that can only happen if the person typing the password walks away before submitting. I don't think there's a lot of risk.

Comment: @bastos.sergio I thought the point of a password box, or textmode to be set to password, is to mask the password?

Comment: @bastos.sergio Also I don't see the password that I typed into the textbox in the source of the page when I view it in the browser.

Comment: What you type doesn't get stored in the html (it's stored in memory). If you set the password via codebehind, like the examples below, you will see it in the html.  Remember, there's a reason why sites like facebook, hotmail, etc never load your original password when you ask to change it.  Once you set your password via attributes like *TextBos.Attributes.Add("value", "yourPassword");* you're leaving your site wide open for hackers.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

How desperate are you?

If you're not desperate enough to try anything, anything to get it to work, don't read on. This will not be nice. OK? OK.

The trick is to make the web app think that it's not a password box. In other words, don't use `TextMode="password"`.
Then in `Page_Load`, put `txt_punch.Attributes["type"] = "password"`

That's it. The browser will know it's a password field (and show asterisks or dots), but the server side won't know, so it will send the content to the client as it it were plain text. Of course, this will also put the password in the page source...

Comment: I am not that sure I am that desperate, lol.I have thought about this, before I posted the question. I really wanted to do this in the code behind, or security and what not. But if all else fails. Thanks for you input btw.

Comment: Absolutely easy but after I saw this :)

Comment: This is such a great solution especially if you need to check whether the text has changed. Using the "TextBox.Attributes.Add("value", "yourPassword");" fires your onTextChanged event. Great.

Comment: this works, thank you, just that this, (as in microsoft) is messed up man, what is the point of password type, if not used correctly it will reset password to blank on update...

Comment: @visual It blanks out the password because 1) otherwise it needs to send the password over the line again, which is a security risk, 2) as I said, the password ends up in plain text in the page source (and in the browser's cache on the computer's hard disk), which is a security risk. 3) The password appears like ●●●●●●● on the screen, so the user can't see if they had typos, and they will need to type it again anyway! 4) It's not just Microsoft, everybody does it like this.

Comment: @MrLister, thanks for the explanation, it makes sense, i suppose best logic would be, if update is pressed and password field value is empty, then do not do the update or show "validation" message, "password is required" for update.

Answer (score 15):

When you set the TextMode property of a TextBox to Password the default behaviour is for it not to display the value of the Text property.

This is to prevent unmasked passwords being shown in the HTML source of the page.

One solution is to use an attribute to hold the password value:

```
TextBox.Attributes.Add("value", "yourPassword");
```

[Source](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/12/18/1300.aspx)

Comment: @nate - missed that, sorry. Don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: @nate I don't see where you tried that. I did come up with an alternate solution though...

Comment: The one where you give the textbox an attribute `onchange="78"`?

Comment: Works nicely. `textBox.Attributes["value"] = "password";` in Page_Load instead of `textBox.Text = "password";`.

Comment: Didn't work very long. The content is lost on every postback. That thing is broken. Gotta use `<asp:TextBox type="password"/>` instead of `<asp:TextBox TextMode="Password"/>`. Then the Text property can be used normally.

Answer (score 1):

Based off option one of Kola's answer you can try this:

```
TextBox.Attributes["value"] = "Whatever value goes here";
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set property of textbox to `TextMode="Password"` then in **edit mode** text box display is blank. If you fill value like

```
TextBox.Text = "Password";
```

then not working and you need to enter password again to save form.
You can use Attributes to fill value in textbox like below code.

```
TextBox.Attributes["value"] = "your password value";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an asp.net BUG!! The email validation algorithm is very strict, resulting in the exclusion of some valid emails. If you switch the TextMode from "Password" tp "SingleLine", your code will work.

Comment: Bad answer!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

we cant directly assign values to password text box.
for assign values to text box password we should use textbox attributes

```
Textbox1.Attributes.Add("value",variable/"string");
```